# randomForestSRC

Tags: survival, random-forest

I aim to use random forest survival analysis to predict depression with the competing risk of death. My primary outcome is depression but I read that it is important to control for the competing risks. I have restructured my data so they look like the below:

Status equals to:

- 0 if the patient is not dead and not depressed
- 1 if the patient is depressed
- 2 if the patient is dead.

**Question 1**: Is this the proper formatting for the data? I read lots of forums and it wasn't clear if the data should be long so each respondent has 1 row for each survey.

**Question 2**: to clarify how to use the competing risk of death.

This is the code I have so far:

```
data(patient_depression, package="randomForestSRC")
depression.obj <- rfsrc(Surv(TIME, STATUS) ~ PAIN + SUPPORT,
                        patient_depression, nsplit=5, ntree=100)
```

but I hope to verify it is correct. Unfortunately none of my advisors are familiar with this method so they encouraged me to contact someone familiar.

[image]